# unable to use Python Console when using inquirer

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, inquirer, python-inquirerpy

I want to use the inquirer package from python but I am unable to do so in IntelliJ IDEA (or PyCharm). When I try this simple code below:

```py
import inquirer
questions = [
    inquirer.Editor('long_text', message="Provide long text")
]
answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)
```

this is the result:
[image: input from Python-Console]

> Provide long text: Press < enter > to launch your editor

which looks normal, but I can't type anything. If I try to type (notice how the cursor is below the prompt) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> I get this error message:

[image: error message]

> Previous command is still running. Please wait or press Ctrl+C in console to interrupt

When using the `input()` command built-in from python, everything works as expected.

**environment**
Python 3.11 (via venv)
inquirer 3.1.3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code and error as text, not a screenshot.